# как реализовать отложенное выполнение фоновой задачи на bottle (python)

Tags: python, многопоточность, веб-служба

Хочу на фреймворке bottle написать сервис, который будет раз в некоторое время парсить информацию с других сайтов и добавлять ее в БД. А при получении запроса, выдавать суммированную информацию из базы данных и выдавать ее в виде HTML страницы.
Вопрос в следующем: как заставить приложение на bottle самостоятельно собирать информацию с других сайтов раз в определенное время?

```
from bottle import route, run, template

def parser(time=n):
    # функция парсинга сайтов запускаемая раз в n-минут 

@route('/report/')
def index():
    return template(# суммированная по определенным критериям информация из БД)

run(host='localhost', port=8080)
```

Comment: Предлагаю разделить задачи: напишите скрипт, который будет парсить и в бд добавлять инфу, а вебсервер при запросе `report` будет из базы считывать и формировать отчет

Comment: В оригинале так и сделал, но те кто дали мне эту задачу настояли на многопоточном веб-сервисе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из коробки bottle такого не умеет.

Самый простой способ – написать для этого отдельный скрипт и выполнять его раз в час/день. Например, с помощью [cron](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

Более продвинутый способ – использовать менеджер очередей, например, [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/).

Comment: Celery на мой взгляд слишком громоздкое для такой задачи. Нашел как вариант решение через multiprocessing. http://paste.ofcode.org/9ziuqcBB9DVbmf8Fzr9Bnt На сколько правильно было бы так написать?

Comment: Лучше разнести сайт и скрипт, тогда они будут независимы. Сейчас если при парсинге что-нибудь сломается, сайт будет недоступен, а это не очень. Помимо этого постоянно работающий процесс будет постепенно отъедать память.

Comment: т.е. в функции parser вызывать, в теле бесконечного цикла со слипом, exec(скрипт с парсером)?

Comment: Нет, просто раз в эн минут запускать `python parse.py`, который будет обновлять данные и прекращать выполнение.

Comment: *"Из коробки bottle такого не умеет"* являясь технически корректным, всё таки может исказить правду: bottle распространяется в виде одного файла без зависимостей, кроме небольшого ядра функциональности, чтобы создать wsgi-приложение, *всё остальное на усмотрение пользователя*: какие ORM, i18n, auth, cache, etc использовать (есть отдельные пакеты, но их не обязательно использовать). То есть bottle не включает сейчас и крайне вероятно не будет включать в будущем очередь распределённых задач (отдельно можно разные решения использовать). cron здесь один из простых и (относительно) надёжных решений